# Не отображается RecycleView Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Приложение запускается, но не отображает список RecycleView

MainFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.osinit.internship.databinding.FragmentMainBinding

class MainFragment: Fragment() {

    private var binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        return rootView

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)?.also {
            binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(it)
        }

    }
    override fun onDestroyView(){
        binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding?.recyclerView?.adapter = RecycleMainAdapter(fillList())
    }
    private fun fillList(): List<String> {
        val data = mutableListOf<String>()
        (0..30).forEach { i -> data.add("$i element") }
        return data
    }
}
```

RecycleMainAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
class RecycleMainAdapter(private val names: List<String>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleMainAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
{
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textViewUp: TextView? = null
        var textViewDown: TextView? = null

        init {
            textViewUp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUp)
            textViewDown = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDown)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textViewDown?.text = names[position]
        holder.textViewUp?.text = "РУБЛЬ"
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = names.size
}
```

recyclevies_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="128dp"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="#40404040"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
</LinearLayout> 
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/rates"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.215"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycleview_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.osinit.internship.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.977"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы что-то не то написали в методе, загружающем разметку фрагмента. Согласно [доке](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) должно быть как-то так:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}
```